# MapStruct: Call merge of Child object while merging Parent object

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have two merge methods one for Parent object and one for Child object

```
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(target="childs", source="childs")
})
void merge(@MappingTarget Target result, Source request);

void merge(@MappingTarget ChildTarget result, ChildSource request);
```

now MapStruct generates the implementation of first merge method is as below

```
@Override
    public void merge(Target result, Source request) {
        if ( request == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( result.getChilds() != null ) {
// I want to instruct MapStruct to call merge for Child object
            List<ChildTarget> list = childSourceListToChildTargetList( request.getChilds() );
            if ( list != null ) {
                result.getChilds().clear();
                result.getChilds().addAll( list );
            }
            else {
                result.setChilds( null );
            }
        }
        else {
            List<ChildTarget> list = childSourceListToChildTargetList( request.getChilds() );
            if ( list != null ) {
                result.setChilds( list );
            }
        }
    }

protected List<ChildTarget> childSourceListToChildTargetList(List<ChildSource> list) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<ChildTarget> list1 = new ArrayList<ChildTarget>( list.size() );
        for ( ChildSource childSource : list ) {
            list1.add( childSourceToChildTarget( childSource ) );
        }

        return list1;
    }
```

I tried various annotation but was not able to find any exact solution

Comment: But what is the problem here?

Comment: @Amongalen, actually I am trying to map my input object with existing JPA Entity
so in this case ```ChildSource``` is the object forming from ```JSON Input```
which I am trying to map to ```ChildTarget``` which is my entity object.

So Issue is when there is already existing child Entity and if i just want to update it it is not working like that, because of below code it is removing existing Entity and adding the new Entity with new primary key
```
result.getChilds().clear();
result.getChilds().addAll( list );
```
I want to merge the modify data into existing Child Entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapStruct cannot do this correctly. Check out [here](https://mapstruct.org/faq/#Why-is-it-not-possible-for-MapStruct-to-generate-implementations-for-Iterable-Stream-and-Map-Types-from-update-MappingTarget-methods) why. How to merge a collection is very much related to the use case (as you already found out).

But you can always do this yourself and MapStruct will select that method.

```java
    @Mapping(target="childs", source="childs") // you can omit @Mappings in java8
    void merge(@MappingTarget Target result, Source request);

    default void merge(@MappingTarget List<ChildTarget> result, List<ChildSource> source ) {
       // write whatever merge functionality you desire and call 'merge' for the ChildTarget / ChildSource here
    }  

    void merge(@MappingTarget ChildTarget result, ChildSource request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, one possible solution is to use [expressions](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions):

```java
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(target="childs",
             expression = "java( mergeChilds(target, request) )")
})
void merge(@MappingTarget Target result, Source request);
```

Note that `mergeChilds` must have the following signature:

```java
List<ChildTarget> mergeChilds(Target target, Source source)
```

It could be a `default` method in your interface, for instance, and must contain your domain-specific logic to handle the merge.